# It's possible to perform a selection on a listener, like on("mouseover")

Tags: javascript, d3.js, listener, selection

I'm developing a simple Information Visualization program where it's viewable a worldwide commercial airports where circles is the airports and the LineStrings are the routes between an airport to another airport.

I want to show the routes ONLY where the mouse is over to the airport which is origin to the route.

In my code, instead the routes are showed only when the mouse is over the route.

I ask if is possible to perform a selection (to the route) when I'm on a listener like mouseover.

I know that this snippet doesn't return anything (I try with console.log(d))

```
.on("mouseover",    
            function(d,i) {
                d3.select("h2 span").html(d.name + "<br/>" + d.city + "<br/>" + d.country); 
                d3.select(this)
                .attr("r", 5);  
                g.selectAll("path.arc")
                    .data(function(d) {
                    return linksByOrigin[d.iata] || []; })
                .enter().append("svg:path")
                .attr("class","arc")
                .attr("visibility","visible")
                .attr("d" , function(d) { console.log(d);
                return path(arc(d)); });


             })
```

Where path.arc are the html object for the arc between the airports
linksByOrigin is an array where for each airports which is the origin of the route I have the routes.
And arc(d) is the Object LineStrings with the coordinate

The code which I use for plot the all routes is the follow

```
g.selectAll("path.arc")
            .data(function(d) { 
            return linksByOrigin[d.iata] || []; })
        .enter().append("svg:path")
            .attr("class", "arc")
            .attr("visibility","hidden")
            .attr("d", function(d) { console.log(arc(d));
            return path(arc(d)); });
```

I use visibility hidden for not display the routes when I'm on.

Comment: Your first bit of code is not complete.  What is `.on()` attached to?  Also, can you show relevant html?

Comment: on is attached to circless.selectAll

See the link
[link](http://pastebin.com/XhBJZciS)

mmm I can open the link for my example, what is the error?

Comment: Have a look at this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7608400).

Comment: Hi altocumulus.
The code is similar but the user doesn't use any listener(on mouseover ecc)

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution.
The problem is that I'm using a selector (selectionAll).
Now I change my code to g.append(circle)

```
g.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return positions[i][0]; })
            .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return positions[i][1]; })
            .attr("r",1.5)
.......
```